# hiding the slider input box in jquery

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery Mobile 1.0.

I have this html code.

```
<label for="slider" class="ui-hidden-accessible">
    Input slider:
</label>
<input type="range" name="slider"   id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_slider" value="25" min="0" max="100" />
```

Its rendering like this:
[image]

But I want to remove the red marked part. I want to show only slider part.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of the up/down arrows, you can wrap the input in an element with a specified width/height and `overflow : hidden`:

```
$(".ui-slider-input").wrap($('<div />').css({
    position : 'relative',
    display  : 'inline-block',
    height   : '36px',
    width    : '45px',
    overflow : 'hidden'
}));
```

Or as Frederic Hamidi stated, you can just hide the element all together and only a slider will be visible.

Here is a demo of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/EWQ6n/1/

Also you can hide the input element with CSS (which is nice because you don't have to time the execution of the CSS like you do with JS):

```
.ui-slider-input {
    display : none !important;
}
```

Here is a demo using CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/EWQ6n/2/

**Update**

Instead of using the `!important` keyword, you can also make a more specific CSS rule so it is used over the jQuery Mobile classes. An example would be:

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-slider-input,
.ui-mobile .ui-dialog .ui-slider-input {
    display : none;
}
```

Comment: done with css .ui-slider-input {
    display : none !important;
} it worked for me

Comment: Thanks Jasper - the "!important" part is actually key, otherwise it doesn't work. (In Chrome, at least)

Comment: @Jasper, nice answer....In addtion, what if i want to display the input box ABOVE the slider at the centre??

Comment: @Jasper, this two jsfiddles you linked to are no longer available could you add them again?

Answer (score 5):

```
input.ui-slider-input {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could hide the input control manually:

```
$("#yourPage").live("pageinit", function() {
    $(".ui-slider-input").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to get rid of the up/down arrow use `type="text" data-type="range"`

```
<input type="text" data-type="range" name="slider" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_slider" value="25" min="0" max="100" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do this too, but I also wanted the space to go away. I accomplished this this way (I'm using a range slider):

```
<div data-role="rangeslider" data-mini="true" class="no-number">
    <input type="range" name="Morn"  id="Morn"  data-mini="true" value="720" min="0" max="1439">
    <input type="range" name="Night" id="Night" data-mini="true" value="10800" min="0" max="1439">
</div>
```

Notice I added the .no-number to the div.

Then in css:

```
/* Used to remove the number next to the slider.*/
.no-number .ui-slider-input
{
    display : none;
    width: 0px;
}

/* Used to remove the space where the number was. */
.no-number .ui-rangeslider-sliders
{
    margin: 0 5px; !important
}
```

I'm doing this all as part of a bigger issue, which is that I'm trying to use a range slider for time instead of numbers, so I replaced those elements with a heading I can change with a function to display the time.

This may not be the perfect choice, but I didn't see where to get the space back anywhere, so I thought I would post it here.

Answer (score 1):

When you do it using `CSS` approach, you may break the input filed of other.  So adding the `class="ui-hidden-accessible"` class to the input to hide it.

Remove this `class="ui-hidden-accessible"` from `label`.

**Your approach is correct.  But you need to add `class="ui-hidden-accessible"` to `input` not on the `label`.**

Your code should be like this:

```
<label for="slider">Input slider:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_slider" 
   value="25" min="0" max="100"  class="ui-hidden-accessible"/>
```

Check this [**SAMPLE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ucajok/37/edit)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it still reserves the space on the left side (even though the inputbox is hidden).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="range" name="slider_sodio" id="slider_sodio" value="0" min="0" max="3" step="1" class="ui-hidden-accessible"  />
```

but look that anoy offset

```
.ui-slider-track {
    margin: 0 15px 0 68px;  ----> change to 10
}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to actually show the old code and then the new code with the proper edits in it.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Remove Input Slider As Below :

```
    input.ui-slider-input {
        display: none;
        width: 0;
    }


    .ui-slider-track {
        margin: 0 15px 0 15px !important;
    }
```