# Remove Text Box in slider control in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using this JQM Links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"> </script>
```

i used slider in division. in older version i have used property class="ui-hidden-accessible"
for not showing the textbox beside the slider but in this version its not working. How can i remove this textbox. My code

```
    <label for="slider" class="ui-hidden-accessible">
                        Input slider:</label>
                    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slidstep" step="25"   value="0" min="1" max="100"/>
```

[image]

should I use other version ? or any way to overcome this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
<style type=text/css>
    input.ui-slider-input {
        display : none !important;
    }
</style>
```

http://the-jquerymobile-tutorial.org/jquery-mobile-tutorial-CH19.php

#### See also

> [hiding the slider input box in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912660/hiding-the-slider-input-box-in-jquery)

Answer (score 7):

Remove this `class="ui-hidden-accessible"` from `label`.

**Your approach is correct.  But you need to add `class="ui-hidden-accessible"` to `input` not on the `label`.**

Your code should be like this:

```
<label for="slider">Input slider:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slidstep" step="25"  
      value="0" min="1" max="100" class="ui-hidden-accessible"/>
```

Check this [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ucajok/37/edit)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it still reserves the space for the input box on the left side (even though its invisible).

Answer (score 1):

I have put my slider inside my own div container with particular class ("ui-slider-slider"). Then in my CSS I have target two children elements of my div, that is:

```
div.ui-slider-slider input.ui-input-text {
    display: none;
}
div.ui-slider-slider div.ui-slider-track {
    margin: 0 15px 0 15px !important;
}
```

First rule hides the text box, the second one makes slider full width. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, the following works: `$("#slider").hide();` 
This is because `#slider` is the text-box component of the slider.

Answer (score 0):

For the rangeslider, this is the solution (from Pascal):

```
        input.ui-slider-input {
            display: none;
        }

        .ui-rangeslider .ui-rangeslider-sliders {
            margin: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none of the above methods really worked for me. The following did work.

```
<div class="noinput">
  <input type="range" name="slider" id="slidstep" step="25"   value="0" min="1" max="100"/>
</div>
```

css

```
.noinput .ui-slider-track {
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px !important;
}

.noinput  input.ui-slider-input {
    display : none !important;
}
```