# Change the color of the jquery mobile slider spin button

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, input, slider

I am using a  jquery mobile slider button

```
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider-0" value="25" min="0" max="100" step="5" />
```

The slider automatically generates a text input and in Chrome it also puts a spin button inside of the text input.  Anyone know how to change the color of this spin button?

[image: spin button]

Comment: Hi, could you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this..?

Comment: I doubt a JSFiddle would better demonstrate what I am looking for.  However here is a link to aan image of how this spin buttons currently look, I am wanting to change their color. http://infobrink.com/wp-customImages/spin-button.png

Comment: Just to confirm, could you post the actual working code. But  I am sure what you are seeing is just a scrollbar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989615/remove-text-box-in-slider-control-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: Here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/g6Jr6/) of what I am looking at. Notice how in Chrome the input box adds arrows/spin box - That is what I am trying to change the color on

Comment: Well there is an event handler when the value of the textbox changes via user inout.. So if I write 58 in the textbox the scroller jumps to 58 accordingly.. So all you need to do is create two spin buttons that change the value in the text-box. The existing event handlers would take care of the rest.. :)

Comment: checkout the spinner in jquery ui, maybe it can translate to mobile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can't change the color of the scroll bars/spin button unless they are HTML elements. IE is an exception and allows this, but then again it is not a web standard and not supported anywhere else. As a workaround, you could hide the browser created spin-button and replace it your own custom spin button consisting of DIV tags with appropriate event handlers.

Comment: I was afraid that it would require some sort of work around.  Your suggestion of hiding it then creating my own custom spin box sounds like it might work.

Comment: Yes, that would ideal as it would be cross-browser compatible and give all users a standard look-n-feel. I did a bit of searching and turns out JQuery mobile will add <input type=number .. /> only in webkit browsers (Chrome/Safari) to make it a spin button.. again this is not supported everywhere (eg. in Gecko browsers like Mozilla).. Here is an example to [disable the spin button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975769/disable-webkits-spin-buttons-on-input-type-number)

Answer (score 0):

you can use different [themes](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/themes.html) or use the [theme roller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/)

[image]

copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912660/hiding-the-slider-input-box-in-jquery/8914108#8914108): 
If you just want to get rid of the up/down arrows, you can wrap the input in an element with a specified width/height and `overflow : hidden`:

```
$(".ui-slider-input").wrap($('<div />').css({
    position : 'relative',
    display  : 'inline-block',
    height   : '36px',
    width    : '45px',
    overflow : 'hidden'
}));
```

Comment: from what I have tried the themes only change the input background color.  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-themes.html show different themes, however the spin button on the slider text input box is always the light grey. You must use Chrome to view what I am referring to as the spin buttons are not generated in firefox or IE.

Comment: ok, you are talking about the up-key and down-key buttons to manipulate the slider value which are visible only in Chrome... I have to think about that...

Comment: Yeah, I was not sure exactly what to call them, which is also making it hard to try and search for help

Comment: Thanks for all the responses Taifin, I don't necessarily want to just hide the arrow buttons, but rather color them to match the rest of my theme. Although hiding them I guess will be my plan B